# Error assembling WAR eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

I'm in the process of deploying my eclipse project using Heroku. However when I try to run my project as a maven build I get an error. I've looked everywhere but couldn't find a solution. This is the error I get.

```
BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.497 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-27T15:12:17-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/274M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project maven-demo: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project maven-demo: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:352)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:197)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.execute(WarMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.war.WarArchiver.initZipOutputStream(WarArchiver.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.createArchiveMain(AbstractZipArchiver.java:309)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.execute(AbstractZipArchiver.java:211)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive(AbstractArchiver.java:897)
    at org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.createArchive(MavenArchiver.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.performPackaging(WarMojo.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.execute(WarMojo.java:177)
    ... 26 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

this is my pom.xml file

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.codebind</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-demo</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>twilio-java-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>(6.0,6.9)</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>

</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
        <configuration>
  <appName>com.codebind</appName>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
   <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
   <!--   <webXml>src\main\webapps\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>  --> 
  <processTypes>
     <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main</web>
  </processTypes>

</configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `heroku-maven-plugin` plugin configuration appears to be mixed with the `maven-war-plugin`. Although the `heroku-maven-plugin` at the root of the  section, the configuration contains a reference to the `maven-war-plugin`, rather than having the maven-war-plugin at the root of the  section.

Maven cannot see the reference to the maven-war-plugin where it is, so Maven continues on using it's own reference of the maven-war-plugin (via Maven's 'super pom') to build/package the war...and *that* plugin is what's throwing the error.

If you want to reconfigure the maven-war-plugin to not fail when a web.xml is not found, you'll need to move the `<maven-war-plugin>` in your POM to where it's not nested within the heroku-maven-plugin and move the `<failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>` to the maven-war-plugin's `<configuration>` element as well.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: That Worked! Thank you so much!